# Printin a X with *

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, clion, visual-c++-2012

i wanna print a X with * , i have done the left side of the X but i don't know how to print the other side (flip/mirror) .
if you run this codes it will print just the left side of (X) and now i wanna print the right side of (X) ? so what should i do to complete the (X) using stars(*)? thank you guys.
i was wondering is it possible to do this?(i'm a newbie to programming)

```
#include <iostream>

// Expected output pattern:
//
//    *     *
//     *   *
//      * *
//       *
//      * *
//     *   *
//    *     *

using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Printing X with star(*)" << endl;
   cout << endl;
   int i;
   int p;
   for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

      for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
         if (j > i) break;
         cout << " ";
         cout << "\t";
      }
      cout << "\t\t\t\t";
      for (p = 1; p <= 10; p++) {

         cout << "*";
      }
      cout << endl;

   }
   for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
      for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
         if (j > i) break;
         cout << " ";
         cout << "\t";
      }
      cout << "\t\t\t\t";
      for (p = 1; p <= 10; p++) {
         cout << "*";

      }
      cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I updated your post with the expected output. If the expected output pattern is different from what you want, please correct it.

Comment: the pattern that i wanted is a little diffrent but thank you very much for the edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thank you every one that helped me , i found the answer i wanted after almost 6 hours and here is the answer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Printing X with stars" << endl;
cout << endl;
int i;
int p;
int k;
int s;
int count = 72;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        if (j > i) break;
        cout << " ";
        cout << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\t\t\t\t";
    for (p = 1; p <= 10; p++) {

        cout << "* ";
    }
    for (k=1; k<=count; k++){
        cout << " ";

    }

    count-=8;
    for (s=1; s<=10; s++){
        cout << "* ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
count = 0;
    for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            if (j > i) break;
            cout << " ";
            cout << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\t\t\t\t";
        for (p = 1; p <= 10; p++) {
            cout << "* ";
        }
        for (k=1; k<=count; k++) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        count +=8;

        for (s=1; s<=10; s++){
            cout << "* ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (count == 80) break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, to do the right hand side you have to print more **** on each line in addition to what you already have done. It might help to think of printing each line of the X as printing some **** then some spaces then more **** and reduce the number of spaces each time you get closer to the cross-over point. Does that make sense? This might help get you further (. = space):

```
*......*
.*....*
..*..*
...**
```

and so on

This is one of many ways you could get there:

```
int main()
{
    int size = 8;
    int spacesBefore;
    int spacesBetween = size;
    int numStars = 1;
    // Top half:
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < size/2; i++ ) {
        spacesBetween = size - ( 2 * ( i + 1 ) );
        spacesBefore = i;
        for ( j = 0; j < spacesBefore; j++ )    // before
            cout << " ";
        for ( j = 0; j < numStars; j++ )        // * left
            cout << "*";
        for ( j  = 0; j < spacesBetween; j++ )  // between
            cout << " ";
        for ( j = 0; j < numStars; j++ )        // * right
            cout << "*";
        cout << endl;
    }
    // bottom half, do the same kind of thing but changing the spacings
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you bruce , your right but i have no idea how to do so on the right side .

Comment: Good luck! Can you mark this as the answer if you're satisfied please.

Comment: Regarding your own answer - I ran your code and it prints out a mirrored K on my console. The only way I could get it to print an X correctly was to replace each tab character with 3 spaces. Weird. Oh well, if you're happy with it...

Comment: no you have ran it wrong ran the one above your answer it completely print out X .